# PowerShell Assistance with expanded property

Tags: powershell

I am currently working on a script that will iterate through Group IDs in Azure and provide me with the UPNs that are members of that group.  I have this command that provides me with the output of several key value pairs.

Get-mgdirectoryrolemember -DirectoryRoleId xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx | select-object -expandproperty additionalproperties

I would like to know how I can select just one of these key-value pairs as an output.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.  I piped the command to  foreach-object -membername userPrincipalName